# Execute a query for all tables and fill in data in new one

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the result table with there fields 
 - table_name, min_date, max_date

Here is my query, which I should execute for all tables

```
SELECT MIN(short_date) as FirstDuplicatedDate, MAX(short_date) as LastDuplicatedDate
FROM (SELECT  short_date, type, value,  count(*) as cnt
FROM testTable
GROUP BY  short_date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as Duplicates
```

Then I found out how to get all table names
I do it in this way

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME as name FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
WHERE `TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'test'
AND `TABLES`.`TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'test%'
```

But I don't know how to execute it for all table and fill in the result in a new table.

I tried to do it in this way

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(50)
DECLARE @Command varchar(100);
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME as name FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
WHERE `TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'test'
AND `TABLES`.`TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'test%') as TableNames

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = 'SELECT MIN(short_date) as FirstDuplicatedDate, MAX(short_date) as LastDuplicatedDate
FROM (SELECT  short_date, type, value,  count(*) as cnt
FROM ' + @DB_Name + '
WHERE type = ''test''
GROUP BY  short_date, type, value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as Duplicates'
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

But I got this error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(50) DECLARE
>   @Command varchar(100)' at line 1

**UPD**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData()
BEGIN

DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(50), @Command varchar(100);
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME as name FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
WHERE `TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'test'
AND `TABLES`.`TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'test%_') as TableNames

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = 'SELECT MIN(short_date) as FirstDuplicatedDate, MAX(short_date) as LastDuplicatedDate
FROM (SELECT  short_date, type, value,  count(*) as cnt
FROM ' + @DB_Name + '
WHERE type = ''test''
GROUP BY  short_date, type, value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as Duplicates'
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END;

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor

END;

CALL GetData()
```

Comment: You've tagged both sql-server and mysql. Since your error messages reference mysql, sql-server one must be wrong. Please remove it.

Comment: Thanks. I should have also said to remove t-sql, since that is the flavour of SQL used on SQL-Server (and not on MySQL).

Comment: can you put an example of what you trying to do exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `DELIMITER $$` at the start; add `DELIMITER ;` after `END`.

Get rid of declaring Command.  Instead use `@command`, which does not need to be declared.

Add `SELECT @command;` after the `SELECT @command := ...;` so that we can do some debugging.

The `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` statements need `;` to terminate them.

Test for running out of rows to `FETCH`.

You really need to look at a number of examples of Stored procedures, especially those with cursors.

**Update**

Ugh, I did not spot even half the syntax errors.  This might work (I can't tell because I don't have your particular tables or columns.):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS so42856538;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE so42856538()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

DECLARE _TableName varchar(64);
DECLARE _done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
        WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'test'
          AND `TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'test%';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET _done = TRUE;

OPEN database_cursor;
curs_loop: LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO _TableName;
    IF _done THEN  LEAVE curs_loop;  END IF;
    SET @Command := CONCAT(
           'SELECT MIN(short_date) as FirstDuplicatedDate,
                           MAX(short_date) as LastDuplicatedDate
           FROM ( SELECT  short_date, type, value,  count(*) as cnt
                    FROM ', _TableName, '
                    WHERE type = "test"
                    GROUP BY  short_date, type, value
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) as Duplicates'
                        );
    SELECT _TableName, @command;   -- Debugging (remove if it is clutter)
    PREPARE _sql FROM @command;
    EXECUTE _sql;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _sql;
END LOOP;
CLOSE database_cursor;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL so42856538;
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Did you have a space between `DELIMITER` and `$$`?  What client are you using to send this to the MySQL server?  (I was using the mysql commandline tool.)

Comment: Did you have another `DELIMITER` statement before the `DROP`?

Comment: And the questions from my previous Comment?

Comment: I use InfinityDB

Comment: Try applying my code again -- this time add `SELECT NOW();` immediately before `DELIMITER $$`.

Comment: Great! Works now

Answer (score 1):

right... you might want to try this.

remove this line and run the query again.

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(50), @Command varchar(100);
```

i think in mysql you can just use a variable without declaring it and then cast when necessary.

Answer (score -2):

As far as my knowledge concern this error is due to ,`DELIMETER` and one more thing that you have to apply cursor properly to iterate whole `rowset`.Here in below code i had wrote down `procedure` with `CURSOR`.Make dynamic query and execute that dynamic query using

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @VAR_QRY; EXECUTE stmt;
```

That dynamic query will returns exact output you want.Here i had assuming that you have basic knowledge about `trigger`,`loop` and `Cursor`

Try below code.
Hope this will helps.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ITERATEALLTABLE;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ITERATEALLTABLE()
BEGIN
DECLARE VAR_TABLE varchar(100);
DECLARE VAR_QRY varchar(100);
DECLARE VAR_FINISHED INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE DATABASE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT name AS TableNames
                FROM (
                    SELECT TABLE_NAME as name FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
                    WHERE `TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'test'
                    AND `TABLES`.`TABLE_NAME` LIKE 'test%'
                )Z ;


                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET VAR_FINISHED = 1;

                OPEN DATABASE_CURSOR;
                GET_NEXTRECORD: LOOP

                        FETCH DATABASE_CURSOR INTO VAR_TABLE;

                            IF VAR_FINISHED = 1 THEN 
                            LEAVE GET_NEXTRECORD;
                            END IF;

                            SET @VAR_QRY = CONCAT("SELECT MIN(short_date) as FirstDuplicatedDate, MAX(short_date) as LastDuplicatedDate
                            FROM (SELECT  short_date, type, value,  count(*) as cnt
                            FROM " , VAR_TABLE , " WHERE type = 'test'
                            GROUP BY  short_date, type, value
                            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as Duplicates");

                            PREPARE stmt FROM @VAR_QRY;
                            EXECUTE stmt;

                END LOOP GET_NEXTRECORD;

                CLOSE DATABASE_CURSOR;

END;

CALL ITERATEALLTABLE;
```

Comment: The `VAR_QRY` in the `DECLARE` is totally different than `@VAR_QRY`.